# Export PDF on careers - writing section is ugly

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I thought I would see what the export to PDF option on careers looked like as I am working on my resume. I liked it up until it hit the writing section. It is ugly as can be.

Can you change the look of this sections so it is more like the web view?

Maybe make a minified url if you want the tracking stuff on there.

[image: Screenshot of PDF section]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks again for your report and your patience as we worked through this. The way this used to work was that we would save the detail page URL supplied by the Amazon API unconditionally for books read and written. As you've seen, the URL includes some query string parameters that make it quite long and unattractive on the PDF version of your CV.

I have updated our code to remove the query string parameters prior to saving the URL as they are not needed for the hyperlink to work nor are they needed by us. This update will be pushed to production shortly. I have also updated the hyperlinks for the two books you wrote to use the shorter URL.

**Note to Others**: All other CVs have been left untouched and use the longer URL. If you wish to see the shorter URL, you can search for and update each of the books listed in your CV. If there is sufficient demand, we will look into an automated way to update everyone.